# Tweepy streaming with Flask socketio

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I want to send the live stream of tweets to the client as and when they are received.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)



class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        MyCustomNamespace.tweet_received(status.text)


class MyCustomNamespace(Namespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
        global myStream
        myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
        myStream.filter(track=['love'], async=True)

    def on_disconnect(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def tweet_received(text):
        emit('tweet_response', {'text': text})

socketio.on_namespace(MyCustomNamespace('/'))
```

But I get a `Runtime Error: Working outside of request context` error while running this. How do I approach doing what I want to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `emit()` call that you have in `tweet_received()` does not have the client context to know where to send the data.

You can fix it by adding additional arguments that set the namespace and the recipient(s) of the event. For example:

```
@staticmethod
def tweet_received(text):
    emit('tweet_response', {'text': text}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
```

This version is going to emit to all clients on the `/` namespace. You may need to change this to what works best for your application, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I was getting a `Out of application context` after this got fixed so I added a `message_queue` parameter `socketio = SocketIO(app,message_queue="redis://localhost:8000")` Now I don't see that error but neither the client nor the server respond anything.